# What is the difference between self->quit() and self->send_exit(self)?

Tags: c++-actor-framework

I have written an actor that is basically the consumer in an N:1 producer/consumer pattern.  This actor holds a smart_ptr reference to an object that implements all the data sharing protocol stuff our customer wants.  I also want this actor to be able to trigger a system-wide controlled shutdown if the protocol object receives a shutdown command.

```
#include "PublishActor.h"

PublishState::PublishState(PublishActor::pointer self, std::shared_ptr<CanPublish> publisher) :
    self_(self),
    publisher_(publisher) {}

PublishActor::behavior_type PublishState::make_behavior() {
    publisher_->addShutdownListener(this);
    self_->attach_functor([](const caf::error& reason) {
        std::cout << "Publishing Actor shutting down: " + caf::to_string(reason) << std::endl;
        });
    return {
        [this](do_publish) {
            publisher_->publishData();
        }
    };
}

void PublishState::doShutdown() {
    //self_->send_exit(self_, caf::exit_reason::user_shutdown);
    self_->quit(caf::exit_reason::user_shutdown);
}
```

This actor is linked to another actor called "SupervisorActor" and all the other actors in my system are linked to Supervisor.  My thinking is, if I can get PublishActor to shutdown then the linking will shutdown everything else as well.

Basically this works beautifully if PublisherActor uses self->send_exit(self) (see above).  But if I use self->quit nothing shuts down (even itself).  I was looking at the description of quit here, and it looked exactly like what I wanted:

[image]

I'm not overriding on_exit (unless attaching that functor does more than I think it does).  What am I missing?

Comment: That's odd, because actors internally simply call `self->quit(reason)` in the default exit message handler. Is really only the actor itself calling `doShutdown()`? Functions of actors are not thread-safe, since the concurrency model of actors relies on message-passing.

Comment: `doShutdown()` is defined here in the publishactor but the actor itself doesn't actually call `doShutdown()`.  `doShutdown()` is a callback function for the "publisher" class (notice `publisher_->addShutdownListener(this)`).  The publisher class is the only place `doShtudown()` is ever called.

Comment: Calling member functions on an actor from the outside is unsafe. Sending it an exit message is perfectly fine and the intended way to tell an actor to quit.

Comment: So is it possible for a non-actor to send a message to an actor?  I want to use a pure abstract class (`CanPublish` for instance) to decouple the actor message handler from the message implementation.  This way I can easily swap out implementations as needed.  I think this is most analogous to the Strategy Pattern.  So the implementation class of `CanPublish` is not an actor but it needs to tell its actor to do something.  How else could this be accomplished?

Comment: Yes, you can send actors messages from non-actor contexts. For sending actors exit messages from "outside", you can use anon_send_exit: https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/0.18.5/libcaf_core/caf/send.hpp#L127.